# I am trying to print only the first 5 lines of a file in python

Tags: python

I want to print out only the first 5 lines of a file but when the number of lines gets bigger than 5, it prints out the lines more than one time. here is my code:

```
numLines = 0
with open("points_sorted", "r") as f:
  for line in f:
    pointsList = line.split()
    numLines += 1
    if numLines >= 5:
      from itertools import islice
      with open("points_sorted") as myfile:
        head = list(islice(myfile, 5))
        print(head)
```

And this is my file:

```
101 
87 M
71 Ko
55 Ko
15 Ko
15 M
0 M Ko
```

Can someone help me with my program?

Comment: Do you mind to format your code?

Comment: Can you show example of the file?

Comment: Your code printing any line after 5-th because of this ` if numLines >= 5: ... print(head)`

Comment: You're opening the file twice, I don't think you mean to do that

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `break` statement to exit your loop after your condition is met:

```
numLines = 0
with open("points_sorted", "r") as f:
  for line in f:
    pointsList = line.split()
    numLines += 1
    if numLines >= 5:
      break
```

You can also use `enumerate()` so that you don't have to count lines manually:

```
with open("points_sorted", "r") as f:
  for numLines, line in enumerate(f):
    pointsList = line.split()
    if numLines >= 4: # counting now starts at 0 instead of 1
      break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try in this way

`f.readline()` allow you two read file line by line

```
with open("points_sorted", "r") as f:
 cnt = 5
 while(cnt > 0):
   pointsList = f.readline().split()
   cnt = cnt -1
```

you can do any operations between while loop and modify the count according to your need